# SPO - Add Document Library to Quick Launch using Powershell

Tags: powershell, spo

As part of an SPO site creation script, I'm trying to get newly created document libraries automatically added to the Quick Launch navigation links.

I'm running this code:

```
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName,$password)

$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $SPOCredentials

$web = $Ctx.Web
    $navColl = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
    $newNavNode = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
    $newNavNode.Title = "External Documents"
    $newNavNode.Url = "External Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
    $newNavNode.AsLastNode = $false

$navColl.Add($newNavNode)

    $web.Update()
    $Ctx.Load($navColl)        
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

But it's returning this:

```
format-default : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], CollectionNotInitializedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `$web.Update()` and check ? Its not needed

Comment: can you change the URL to `$newNavNode.Url = $siteUrl +  "External Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"` and check ?

Comment: Still the same... If I run it line by line, it is when I get to this part that I see the initialization error:

'$navColl.Add($newNavNode)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to initialise the Navigation Node collection.

Just add `$Ctx.Load($navColl.Add($newNavNode))` to the script

Modify your code as below so that it looks something like :

```
$web = $Ctx.Web
$navColl = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$newNavNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
$newNavNode.Title = "External Documents"
$newNavNode.Url = $siteUrl + "External Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
$newNavNode.AsLastNode = $false

$Ctx.Load($navColl.Add($newNavNode))
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: cheers, happy to help ! :)  You can mark it as answer by ticking the checkmark besides the answer. You can refer how to do that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)